# Add Enter as Hot Key for Multiple Forms in a single Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application that already in use.
I need to add few hotkeys to it like `Enter` should trigger some already existing `Button.Click` events.
It has multiple forms.

1st form has
`<button name="Search" type="button" class="abc" disabled>Search</button>`

2nd on has
 `<button type="button" class="xyz" id="show" ">Show</button>`

3rd ....
The button click events are in a .js file

```
$('body').on('click', '#search-form button[name=Search]', function () {
        //implementaion
    });

$('body').on('click', '#Show-Change', function () {
        //implementaion
    });
```

Now when I am using the Search form , its has multiple drop-downs to be selected.
When I press enter the `Search.Click` should be triggered (should behave same as when I click on the `SEARCH` button), when I am using the 2nd form the show, the click event should trigger.

The first form is like a menu form on the left side of the form. The second one is a popup form. I am new to `.js` and need help. I need to implement these on couple of similar forms in the application.

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $('#search-form button[name=Search]').click();
        }
});
```

But this works only for the `search.click` button, and is triggered whenever `Enter` is pressed, irrespective of the form I am on.
Not sure how to make it generic enough to handle this on every form that needs `enter` as a Hotkey.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've already written?

Comment: I have added the code above. Thanks!

Comment: Could you more of your HTML code ?